# brother 7040 (all-in-one) printing works but I can't use scanner

Tags: scanner, brother

Linux newcomer on an older machine, I used the brother.com suggested files and got the printer working but not the scanner. simple scan says "failed to scan, unable to connect to scanner."

I'm not sure what this is but I think it's important to this problem.

```
mobius@mobius-Dimension-2400:~$ sudo dpkg -l | grep Brother
[sudo] password for mobius: 
ii  brdcp7040lpr                                  2.0.2-1                                    i386         Brother DCP-7040 LPR driver
ii  brscan-skey                                   0.2.4-1                                    i386         Brother Linux scanner S-KEY tool
ii  brscan3                                       0.2.13-1                                   i386         Brother Scanner Driver
ii  cupswrapperdcp7040                            2.0.2-1                                    i386         Brother DCP7040 CUPS wrapper driver
```

********New machine, same printer -- same problem. Update!!!*****

```
 siren@siren-HP-Pavilion-Desktop-PC-570-p0xx:~$ sudo dpkg -l | grep 
 Brother
 [sudo] password for siren: 
 ii  printer-driver-brlaser                          4-1                                          
 amd64        printer driver for (some) Brother laser printers
 ii  printer-driver-ptouch                           1.4.2-3                                      
 amd64        printer driver Brother P-touch label printers
```

I have installed the 7040 drivers here:  https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadhowto.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=dcp7040_us_as&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625 
     sudo su
     bash linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.1-1 DCP-7040

I now get back:

> ```
>  siren@siren-HP-Pavilion-Desktop-PC-570-p0xx:~$ sudo dpkg -l | grep 
>  Brother
>  [sudo] password for siren: 
>  ii  brdcp7040lpr:i386                               2.0.2-1                                      
>  i386         Brother DCP-7040 LPR driver
>  ii  brscan-skey                                     0.2.4-1                                      
>  amd64        Brother Linux scanner S-KEY tool
>  ii  brscan3                                         0.2.13-1                                     
>  amd64        Brother Scanner Driver
>  ii  cupswrapperdcp7040:i386                         2.0.2-1                                      
>  i386         Brother DCP7040 CUPS wrapper driver
>  ii  printer-driver-brlaser                          4-1                                          
>  amd64        printer driver for (some) Brother laser printers
>  ii  printer-driver-ptouch                           1.4.2-3                                      
>  amd64        printer driver Brother P-touch label printers
> ```

Trying "Simple Scan" returns "no scanners connected"

Comment: You appear to be using the current version of software from Brother.  Are you connecting over a network, and do you have a firewall installed?

Comment: I am online with the standard firewall enabled.

Comment: Just for grins, can you disable your firewall for a short time and try the scanner?  I use an HP product, which scans just fine but which cannot be detected and installed while the firewall is active.

Comment: It didn't give me any noticeable change. I tried unplugging and reattaching the USB cable, running updates and rebooting without getting a scan to run.

Comment: I don't understand. This comment has a link that solves the problem but it was a "comment" not an answer. "I no longer have that printer, so it'd be hard to troubleshoot with you, but a quick Google search led me to this website: sigmdel.ca/michel/program/misc/… – Daniel Pavlovsky 2 days ago" I also can't upvote my answer which is a reiteration of his answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a Brother DCP7020 all-in-one printer/scanner.  I found a solution, nominally for an MFC-7420, that the original author suggested “...should work for any of the Brother models that use the brscan2 driver.”  This proved to be the case for my 7020 and, since your 7040 sounds like a closely-related model, may well be appropriate for you also.  The complete set of instructions that I used are posted at: [Getting a DCP7020’s scanner to work](https://linuxnorth.wordpress.com/2013/09/26/getting-a-dcp7020s-scanner-to-work/)

Answer (score 0):

After installing all the drivers including brscan2 on my 64-bit system, the scanner still didn't work until I did this:

```
cd /usr/lib64
sudo cp -pr lib* sane /usr/lib
```

As the previous poster suggests in the link he posted.

Comment: I tried: siren@siren-HP-Pavilion-Desktop-PC-570-p0xx:/usr/lib64$ sudo cp -pr lib* sane /usr/lib
[sudo] password for siren: 
siren@siren-HP-Pavilion-Desktop-PC-570-p0xx:/usr/lib64$ 

S, I assume it worked but I get the same scanner not found error

Comment: sudo gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane1.rules was where the file was located, it seems. I edited it anyway but don't think it worked. It is in /lib64 but SimpleScan still doesn't recognize scanner.

Comment: I no longer have that printer, so it'd be hard to troubleshoot with you, but a quick Google search led me to this website: https://www.sigmdel.ca/michel/program/misc/brother_dcp7040_scanner_on_ubuntu_1710_en.html

Comment: Thank you. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved

I needed to create a Brother3.conf file in /etc/sane.d

with this inside:

#Brother DCP-7040 usb 0x04f9 0x01e9

as detailed here: https://www.sigmdel.ca/michel/program/misc/brother_dcp7040_scanner_on_ubuntu_1710_en.html#how

Thanks, Daniel for the link

Answer (score 0):

For myself, after installing Brother drivers from their website, all I needed to do extra was use:

```
$ scanimage -L
device `brother4:bus4;dev5' is a Brother DCP-7065DN USB scanner
```

Then `simple-scan` started working.